# How to add a word at the beginning of multiple lines in vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim,

How do i add a word at the beginning of all lines?
Also how do i add it at end?

Eg.. 
If i have

```
A
B
C
D
```

I want to make it to

```
int A =
int B =
```

etc..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use visual block mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>) to select the column you want, and then hit <kbd>I</kbd>, type the characters you want, and then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>

So in this case, you'd put your cursor on `A`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, go down to `D`, hit <kbd>I</kbd> and type `int` (it'll only appear on the first line while you type it), and then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> at which point it'll apply that insert to all visually selected portions.

This works for anywhere in the document, beginning of line or end of line.

`:he v_b_I` for more info on Visual Block Insert

Comment: This will work for empty lines only if `virtualedit` is not empty.

Comment: +1 as this is the most general solution.  For appending see `:help v_b_A` rather than `v_b_I`

Comment: Interesting that `visual block` is different that `visual mode`

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
:%s/^/at the beginning/
:%s/$/at the end/
```

Answer (score 4):

`:%s/.\+/int & =`

+ won't match on empty lines

Answer (score 2):

A global substitute should do i:

```
:%s/.\+/int & =/
```

This is how it works: in the second part of the substitution (ie in the `int & =`) the ampersand is replaced with what machted in the first part (the `.*`). Since `.*` matches the entire line, each line is subsituted as wanted.

If you have empty lines (in which you don't want to have any replacements), you could go with a

```
:%s/^\S\+$/int & =/
```

Comment: $0? This is for Perl or C++ (TR1)

Comment: $0 is probably in another regular expression based language.

Comment: In vim, '&' expands to the entire matched pattern.

Comment: For those used to `$0`, there is also `\0` as an equivalent alternative to `&`.  This follows with `\1`, `\2` etc for groups.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to copy just the first word, then do:

```
:%s/^\w\+/int & =/g
```

If you want to preserve indentation, then do:

```
:%s/^\(\s*\)\(\w\+\)/\1int \2 =/g
```